# Updating game records in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

We have game records organised as following:

[image]

A player is allowed to play the game at different levels and a highscore table is kept to show the **top 10 list of game records**. Each game record on the highscore table contains a set of attributes, for example, the player's name, the total score obtained and the level from which the score was obtained. The list of game records is normally sorted from highest to the lowest score, indicating the rank of players from the highest to lowest level.

We have to implement

```
 public GameRecord[] updateGameRecords(GameRecord[] oldRecords, GameRecord newRecord)
```

in the following way:

1. If there exists a record with same name and same level as newRecord then we update that record if the newRecord has a greater score and we then sort the oldRecords and return it.
   Otherwise, go to step 2
2. If the number of records with the same level as that of newRecord are **less than 10**, then we insert the new record in oldRecords and sort it and then return it.Otherwise, go to step 3.
3. If there is any record with poorer score at the same level as newRecord then we replace the record with lowest score of that level , since number of records for a given level cannot exceed 10 and then we sort and return oldRecords.

This have so far been my code:

```
public GameRecord[] updateGameRecords(GameRecord[] oldRecords, GameRecord newRecord) {
    int index = -1, r = 0;
    boolean break_loop = false, same_name_level = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldRecords.length; ++i) {
        while (i < oldRecords.length && newRecord.getLevel() < oldRecords[i].getLevel()) {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
        while (i < oldRecords.length && i < oldRecords.length && newRecord.getLevel() == oldRecords[i].getLevel()) {
            if (r == 0)
                index = i;
            ++r;//r is number of records with same level
            if (!break_loop && newRecord.getName().equals(oldRecords[i].getName())) {
                same_name_level = true;
                break_loop = true;
                if (newRecord.getScore() > oldRecords[i].getScore()) {
                    oldRecords[i].setScore(newRecord.getScore());
                }
            }
            ++i;
        }
        if (break_loop == true)
            break;
    }

    if (break_loop == true) {
        Util.sort(oldRecords);
        return oldRecords;
    }

    if (r > 0 && r < 10 && same_name_level == false) {
        GameRecord[] temp = oldRecords.clone();
        oldRecords = new GameRecord[oldRecords.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, oldRecords, 0, temp.length);
        oldRecords[temp.length] = newRecord;
        Util.sort(oldRecords);
        return oldRecords;
    }

    if (r == 10) {
        if (oldRecords[index + 9].getScore() < newRecord.getScore())
            oldRecords[index + 9].setScore(newRecord.getScore());
        Util.sort(oldRecords);
        return oldRecords;
    }

    if (r == 0) {
        GameRecord[] temp = oldRecords.clone();
        oldRecords = new GameRecord[oldRecords.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, oldRecords, 0, temp.length);
        oldRecords[temp.length] = newRecord;
        Util.sort(oldRecords);
        return oldRecords;
    } else
        return oldRecords;
}
```

It is working fine but this is linear time complexity code that is it takes O( oldRecords.length ) + **time taken by Util.sort()** function which makes the total running time non-linear.

Can you suggest me a linear time algorithm.

Comment: Any insights in how Util.sort sorts the array? Is GameRecord comparable? What are the internal data types of GameRecord?

Comment: Can't you just keep the first 10 records? This way your algorithm, which should be of O (nlogn) complexity, runs in a very small time

Comment: @Tobias Stoeckmann  No its not comparable and the internal data types are String for name, integer for score and level. Util.sort uses quicksort and mergesort neither of which is linear.

Comment: Following up on this, I further assume that oldRecords is already sorted when supplied as an argument. My assumption is based on your r==10 handling.

Comment: @TobiasStoeckmann  thats right.

Comment: In that case you don't really have to call sort. Remember the proper index to place your new value into and move the other values around like you already do with arraycopy.

Comment: If your code works, then ask here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Are you really asking about O(n) algorithm instead of O(n log n) for a situation when n is 10?

Comment: Why are you not interested in a better runtime, like O (N log N), which could be achieved through a quick sort or merge sort? Also, Tobias raises a very good point. If your table is already sorted, you can index the table and know exactly where to put your next item, making it unnecessary to sort every time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain a sorted list upon insertion or update of a record, it is not necessary to sort the entire list again; it is sufficient to move this record to the proper place. Moreover, because we never change the level, and only increase the score, we know that this record only moves up.

That is, after you are done inserting or updating the record, I'd invoke the following method:

```
void moveToProperPlace(GameRecord[] records, int index) {
    int newIndex = findCorrectIndex(records, index);
    if (newIndex != index) {
        GameRecord record = records[index];
        System.arrayCopy(records, newIndex, records, newIndex + 1, index - newIndex);
        records[newIndex] = record;
    }
}

int findCorrectIndex(records, index) {
    int i = index;
    do {
        i--;
    } while (i >= 0 && higher(records[index], records[i]);
    return i + 1;
}

boolean higher(GameRecord x, GameRecord y) {
    return x.getScore() > y.getScore() || (x.getScore() == y.getScore && x.getLevel() > y.getLevel());
}
```

Since presorted data is quite common, a well designed sort implementation from a standard library may actually fall back to such an insertion sort if it detects that the data is nearly sorted, providing O(n) sort for inputs where only a constant number of elements is in the wrong place, and O(n log n) otherwise. In particular, [`java.util.Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) and [`java.util.Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) are implemented that way. If your `Util.sort` is also implemented like that, your algorithm is already O(n).

In any case, unless you have thousands of levels and millions of games to be recorded each second, the difference between an O(n) and O(n log n) is unlikely to have a noticeable effect on the execution time of your program.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) solution is:

```
static final int MAX = 10;

static void bubbling(int[] recs) {
    for (int i = recs.length - 1; i > 0; --i)
        if (recs[i] > recs[i - 1]) {
            int temp = recs[i];
            recs[i] = recs[i - 1];
            recs[i - 1] = temp;
        }
}

static int[] updateRecord(int[] oldRecs, int newRec) {
    int oldLen = oldRecs.length;
    int newLen = oldLen < MAX ? oldLen + 1 : MAX;
    int[] newRecs = new int[newLen];
    System.arraycopy(oldRecs, 0, newRecs, 0, oldLen);
    if (newLen > oldLen || newRec >= newRecs[newLen - 1]) {
        newRecs[newLen - 1] = newRec;
        bubbling(newRecs);
    }
    return newRecs;
}
```

`GameRecord` is changed to `int` to simplify the problem.